# flash activex in wpf issue

Tags: wpf, flash, activex

I know how to host a flash activex in wpf, but there a issue to that.
After I reinstall my os , my app failed to laod a flash file, 
but after I opened the flash file with web browser and restart my app,
my app worked again.  is there some configuration I have to do ?